# Keep specific bits from calculation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is it possible to keep only the last X bits from a calculation like this?:

```
a_register <= some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}}
//can it be done in one line of code? Like:
//a_register <= some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}} [X:0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign to concatenated wires, with a temp variable for the LSBs which should make it clear to synthesis tools that those bits are not used and could be optimised away.

```
wire [4:0] temp;

assign {a_register, temp} = some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}};
```

or

```
reg [4:0] temp;

always @(posedge clk) begin 
  {a_register, temp} <= some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}};
end
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to retain only the last N bits of a calculation, you need only make `a_register` size N. The assignment will take only the last N bits of the calculation. If you need `a_register` to be larger for some reason, you can always only select the last N bits of `a_register` and assign that the value:

```
a_register[X:0] <= some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}};
```

What you have currently does not work; but you can always use a temp value to store the result of the calculation and take `[X:0]` of that.

```
assign temp = some_addr - {some_addr[(width-1):limit],limit{1'b0}};
...
a_register <= temp[X:0];
```

(Though its not 1 line)